# Violation of primary key constraint even if I have delete in my procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cannot insert into table more than once due to primary key duplicity even if I have delete in my procedure. Can you please help me guys?

```
BEGIN
    IF @operace = 'v'
        DELETE
        FROM lcs.vztahy_formulare
        WHERE lcs.vztahy_formulare.zamid IN (
                SELECT crossTable.uzivatel
                FROM #tempCrossTable crossTable
                WHERE crossTable.uzivatel = lcs.vztahy_formulare.zamid
                    AND crossTable.cislo_vztahu = lcs.vztahy_formulare.cislo_vztahu
                    AND crossTable.cislo_poradace = lcs.vztahy_formulare.cislo_poradace
                    AND crossTable.strana = lcs.vztahy_formulare.strana
                    AND lcs.vztahy_formulare.type = 2
                )

    IF @operace = 'v'
        INSERT INTO lcs.vztahy_formulare
        SELECT crossTable.uzivatel
            ,crossTable.cislo_poradace
            ,crossTable.vztazeneVztahy
            ,0
            ,crossTable.strana
            ,1
            ,0
            ,2
        FROM #tempCrosstable crossTable
END
```

Here is table structure

```
CREATE TABLE lcs.vztahy_formulare (
    zamid INT NOT NULL
    ,cislo_poradace INT NOT NULL
    ,cislo_vztahu INT NOT NULL
    ,poradi INT NOT NULL
    ,strana CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    ,relation_volume_type INT NOT NULL
    ,poradi_archiv INT NOT NULL
    ,type INT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_vztahy_formulare_1__30] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (
        [zamid] ASC
        ,[cislo_poradace] ASC
        ,[cislo_vztahu] ASC
        ,[strana] ASC
        ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF
        ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        ,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [lcs].[vztahy_formulare] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__vztahy_fo__relat__7917DB30] DEFAULT((1))
FOR [relation_volume_type]
GO

ALTER TABLE [lcs].[vztahy_formulare] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__vztahy_fo__porad__7A0BFF69] DEFAULT((0))
FOR [poradi_archiv]
GO

ALTER TABLE [lcs].[vztahy_formulare] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF__vztahy_for__type__3E77CEFD] DEFAULT((1))
FOR [type]
GO
```

lcs.vztahy_formulare.**zamid** equals #tempCrossTable.**uzivatel** 
lcs.vztahy_formulare.**cislo_vztahu** equals #tempCrossTable.**cislo_vztahu** 
lcs.vztahy_formulare.**cislo_poradace** equals #tempCrossTable.**cislo_poradace** 
lcs.vztahy_formulare.**strana** equals #tempCrossTable.**strana**

Selecting data from table lcs.vztahy_formulare

```
SELECT *
FROM lcs.vztahy_formulare f
WHERE f.zamid = 51048910
```

returns
[data from lcs.vztahy_formulare(link on screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY9TE.png)

It returns 3 rows (with type 2) and it's correct. So delete should work with type = 2.


If I want to run this insert again I have to delete it manually via simple delete statement.

```
DELETE
FROM lcs.vztahy_formulare
WHERE lcs.vztah_formulare.zamid = 51048910
```

Comment: We don't know your table structures. We don't even know which column(s) make up your PK here. Please add some appropriate `create table` statements and some sample data to help us to understand what's even *happening* here.

Comment: I added table structure. If you need more information tell me and I will try my best to give you everything you need.

Comment: `type` isn't in the PK and yet your delete only deals with items where `type` is 2 - so the obvious would be if there's some other row in there with a different `type` value.

Comment: Damien, I added returned data from table. Insert gave me correct results but still I can insert it only once :/

Comment: 1. use fileds list in insert statement; 2. likely you mistyped column in insert - instead of `crossTable.vztazeneVztahy` you have to use `crossTable.cislo_vztahu`

Comment: Thank you Arvo ! Now insert works multiple times as I wished :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are using the wrong field in your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO lcs.vztahy_formulare
        SELECT crossTable.uzivatel
            ,crossTable.cislo_poradace
            ,crossTable.cislo_vztahu
            ,0
            ,crossTable.strana
            ,1
            ,0
            ,2
        FROM #tempCrosstable crossTable
```

Comment: Thank you Rogério Carvalho Batista. Now it works ! :)